# Visual Studio 2012 native C++ DLL x86 compilation

Tags: c++, dll, windows-8, x86, visual-studio-2012

I have recently upgraded my toolset from Win 7 x86 / Visual Studio 2010 to Win 8 x64 / Visual Studio 2012.  However, now my native C++ dll compiles as x64 rather than x86.  I haven't done anything other than move the code to the new O/S and load it into VS2012.

Does anyone know how I can force it to compile for x86?

Comment: In the Configuration Manager (right-click on the solution in the explorer bar), have you set the platform to Win32, and not x64?

Comment: Yes, the platform is set to Win32.  Previously it worked fine, until I upgraded to VS2012.  If I choose New Project Platform I can choose between Arm, Itanium and x64 - no x86 option.

Comment: (That's because Win32 means the same thing as x86 in VS2012.) Try going into your project's Properties --> Linker --> Advanced --> Target Machine and setting that to  MachineX86.

Comment: Thanks Archimaredes - that seems to have done the trick.  If you want to send this an answer, I will accept it for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to your project's property pages, find the **Linker** -> **Advanced** -> **Target Machine** option, and make sure it is set to **MachineX86**.

Answer (score 1):

Go to  **Build**--> **Configuration Manager**  --> **Active Solution Platform**
and change it to x86.

You can also confirm your specific project Platform, by looking for the project name in the same window and the Platform that is applied to it.

Comment: The active platform is set to Win32, which is the only Platform that is configured.  If I choose to create a new one x86 is missing.  Any ideas?