# "Librarian" rather than "Linker" shown in VS2015 DLL project

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2015

I have a DLL project in Visual Studio 2015 with properties:

[image: DLL, but still Librarian]

However on the left hand side, I see "Librarian" rather than "Linker" options. Also on build I get undefined symbols for all referenced libraries (the project references a few projects in the solutions which build as static lib).

To note:

- I converted the project from a static lib to a DLL by changing the "Configuration Type" option.
- I have applied, saved, closed, reopened
- Linked projects are of same type (e.g. Debug/x64) for this solution configuration.

This could be a VS2015 bug?

Note perhaps similar question for previous version of Visual Studio
[In Visual Studio 2012 what is the difference between Librarian and Linker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22026008/in-visual-studio-2012-what-is-the-difference-between-librarian-and-linker)
(however the question doesn't specify that it's a DLL project)

Comment: It does not win any prizes.  You forgot to select "All Platforms" in the Platform combo box.  So your Win32 (aka x86) platform probably still has the wrong Configuration Type.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but all configurations and platforms are set to Dynamic Library

Comment: Not able to duplicate with VS 2015 Update 1. Once the config type is changed to `dll` the `Librarian` section changes to `Linker`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the DLL project had a property sheet which sets the project as a static library, and had a libraries section.

It seems setting your project settings to DLL cannot override this kind of property sheet.