# Visual Studio 2019 - How to add a .lib to a c++ library project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dependencies

I created a c++ library with VS2019

- my other projects see and use that library fine, they compile fine
- but my library itself cannot be compiled as it complains about missing entry points for a depending lib

**I want to add that .lib file, like I did for my other projects**

but in the library project settings, **there is no linker option**, so I cannot tell it to use the missing .lib dependency

how do I resolve this ?

thanks for helping me on this

[edit] strangly enough SDL libraries dont cause any problem (becos of dll's ?) while nfd.lib has no dll

maybe the reason I cannot link my library with static libraries ?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQvE4.png)

Comment: Did you look under the "Librarian" menu? [In Visual Studio 2012 what is the difference between Librarian and Linker?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22026584)

Answer (score 1):

> but my library itself cannot be compiled as it complains about missing entry points for a depending lib

The library project can only be built but not compiled. After you finish building the .lib project, you will get a .lib file like this in the debug folder. And then you could add it to your C++ project.

According to your description, If you want to add a .lib to a .lib project? If so, I suggest you could try to add the name of the .lib file with its extension to Additional Dependencies. `Librarian -> General -> Additional Dependencies`. Here is the equivalent of linker input. And then add the path to the .lib file to the Additional Library Directories. `Librarian -> General -> Additional Library Directories`.Here is the equivalent of linker General.

Comment: @Jean Jean Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.